# Spark : How is memory managed on executors when RDD's are created?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My Spark application is currently causing executors to die due to YARN attempting to exceed the memory limit.  I can't seem to find in the documentation or the O'Reilly book I bought how creating RDD's allocates memory on executors.  Could someone walk me through what happens in the following code snippet?

```
N = 10
array = numpy.random.random_float(N)

# Is the array actually partitioned and serialized out when this is executed?
# Or when an action using this rdd is called?  At this point,
# I would expect 1 float, or 4 bytes on each executor.
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(array, 10)

# Transformations return new rdd's, so now I would expect each executor 
# to have 2 floats on it, one from rdd, and one from rdd2, so 8 bytes.
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: x + 2)

# Here is where things get murky.  Would this cause 8 bytes of memory to be used
# to account for the intermediate product of rdd1.map(lambda x: x -2)?  
# So in Spark's calculations, if we would now require space for 
# 4 floats, one for each rdd1/2/3 and one for the intermediate?
rdd3 = rdd1.map(lambda x: x - 2).map(lambda x: x * 2)

# Is this the point where each executor actually has the memory allocated? 
# And since I only call collect() on the first rdd,
# would only 4 bytes be sent out to each executor?
rdd1.collect()

#How about now?
rdd2.collect()
```

Comment: The `collect()` method takes the results from all of your executors and sends it back to the driver. This is the most likely reason to cause OOM.

Comment: Right, but it's the executors that I'm curious about and the executors are the ones that are breaching the limit.

Comment: About your first question, the `collect()` method is a spark action which triggers the transformations like `parallelize()`, `map()`, etc.
So only when executing an action the job is starting to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Unit test that uses `sc.parallelize()` and put a break point after this line is executed. I do not see any memory allocation being logged until the subsequent `collect()` is called.

Java code...

```
JavaRDD<String> fooBars = sparkCtx.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList("foo", "bar"));
JavaRDD<String> abcs = fooBars.map(f -> "abc");
abcs.collect();   // break point here
```

From the log when collect() is executed...

```
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  DAGScheduler:59 - Got job 0 (collect at MyTest.java:40) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  DAGScheduler:59 - Final stage: Stage 0(collect at MyTest.java:40)
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  DAGScheduler:59 - Parents of final stage: List()
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  DAGScheduler:59 - Missing parents: List()
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  DAGScheduler:59 - Submitting Stage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at RddFactory.java:42), which has no missing parents
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  MemoryStore:59 - ensureFreeSpace(1416) called with curMem=0, maxMem=991753666
2016-02-03 15:49:14 INFO  MemoryStore:59 - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1416.0 B, free 945.8 MB)
```

This is consistent with the Spark documentation that explains that the lazy evaluation for non-terminating functions (e.g. `map()`) are not executed until a terminating function is used (e.g. `collect()`). This example also shows that `parallelize()` is also considered a non-terminating function because `ensureFreeSpace...` was not logged until the collect() statement.

To explain your other question about the two collect() statements, Sparks `RDD` objects are immutable, therefore when you call `rdd1.collect()` it creates this `RDD`. If you then call `rdd2.collect()` it will have to create that one as well.

Comment: Thank you for this...I think it's definitely getting close to what I was trying to ask.  Is the "Block broadcast_0 stored as...(1416.0 B, free 945.8 MB)" line a reference to how much information is actually being sent out to all the executors?  I'm playing around now with my own prototype code and have noticed weird results as to the size of the broadcasted memory compared to what I thought I was sending.

Comment: My answer is intended to point you to the log files of the Driver and Executors to determine what is going on. Your question is about memory allocation on the Executor. I suggest rasing another specific question if you're interested about data moving between nodes. The community is happy to answer specific questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this it rather tricky question.

First of all you have include memory that is completely interdependent of the work you perform. It means worker process (at 200MB or so) and memory required to run each Python executor (~30-40MB per interpreter without any additional imports).

Moreover every data which is passed between stages is practically duplicated. First it has to be passed to the workers (JVM) and then piped through sockets to Python interpreters.

Finally there are details of Spark implementation. By default Spark reuses Python interpreters between tasks. It means that temporary objects created in each tasks have to be garbage collected before memory is freed. Usually it shouldn't be a problem but it is definitely something to keep in mind. Moreover data can be spilled to disk if necessary which can make the picture even more complicated.

So while your calculations are more or less correct (assuming you've executed an action and use `float32`) it is only a small part of the picture.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps to explain some of the results I'm seeing.  I wrote up a quick snippet to test sending 1 float each to 4 executors.  The memory broadcast was 746 bytes!  Even weirder was when I tested sending 2 floats to each.  The memory broadcast was the same!  I thought it would at least be 747 bytes, but I clearly don't understand what's happening.